# Why can I access a non-global variable in one module from another in python?

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

Ok, the below code is completely scrap, pointless code I made up; but I find it weird that I can access the variable "b" from the qwerty() function while b was only declared inside while... I thought I could only access it if I declared it globally somehow?

```
x = 14
while (x > 10):
    b = 3
    b += 3
    print(b)
    x -= 1

def qwerty():
    if b == 6:
         print("b can be accessed elsewhere?")

input("")
```

Running this code, "b can be accessed elsewhere?" will be printed... even though b == 6 is referencing the variable b that was declared in the separate while() function.

I guess I am still confused about the properties of global and local variables in python. Can anyone explain why the above happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`while` is not a function.  The only constructs that create their own scopes are `def`, `class`, and generator expressions / comprehensions (depending on version).

```
if True:
    while 1:
        for x in range(1):
            z = 1
        break

def function():
    print(z)

function() # prints 1
```

This works *almost* the same way as inside functions.

```
def function():
    while True:
        x = 5
        break
    def nested():
        print(x)
    nested() # prints 5
    x = 10
    nested() # prints 10
```

I say *almost* because there are a few subtle differences in how you can modify outer variables depending on whether they are global or belong to an enclosing function.

Comment: It's not just `def` and `class` -- genexps and comprehensions (excepting 2.7 listcomps) have their own scopes, at least if I understand the terminology.  That is, `i = 2; s = {i for i in range(10)}; print i` prints 2, not 9.  [Or maybe you wouldn't think of those as "constructs"?  Not sure.]